# ASP Web Services en PHP con NUSOAP

Tags: php, asp.net, webservice, nusoap

He estado tratando de llamar o hacer uso de un web service hecho en ASP y he visto varios posts que tienen ese problema, sin embargo, no encuentro uno con un error como el mío.

Según yo, en mi corta y novata experiencia, se ejecuta bien el código, pero falla en algún proceso al momento de imprimir el resultado.

Esto es lo que he intentado.

```
<?php

require_once ('lib/nusoap.php');
$client = new soapclient ('http://localost/Tintowin_WS/Tintowin_WS.asmx?WSDL', 'wsdl');

$error = $client->getError();
if($error) {
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $error . '</pre>';
}

$variablex = array('llave'=>'XXqrD-5Z4by-6.f5J-2TQlu-TjLrK-007eA-R0l5E-2DQEc-0DhoA-L2y5y-.bJ6u-sjGiB-0W4EA-V0E5o-u3Qqr', 'usuario'=>'mIgueLL', 'password'=>'12387abwxyz');
$regresa = $client->call('WSLoginUsuario', array('variablex'=>$variablex));

if ($client->fault){
echo '<h2>FAULT</h2><pre>';
print_r($regresa);
echo '</pre>';
} else {
    //checa errores
    $error = $client->getError();
    if ($error){
        //muestra el error
        echo '<h1>Error</h1><pre>' . $error . '</pre>';
    }else{
        //muestra el resultado
        echo '<h2>Resultado</h2><pre>';
        print_r($regresa);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}

echo $regresa;

?>
```

EL ERROR ES EL SIGUIENTE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Error 

no transport found, or selected transport is not yet supported!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré que funcionara, les dejo el código a continuación.

```
<?php
$webservice_url = "http://"my ip server"/Tintowin_WS/Tintowin_WS.asmx";

$key = 'XXqrD-5Z4by-6f5J-2TQlu-TjLrK-007eA-R0l5E-2DQEc-0DhoA-L2y5y-bJ6u-sjGiB-0W4EA-V0E5o-u3Qqr';
$user = 'carl0S';
$pass = '0987-abcd';

$request_param = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <WSLoginUsuario xmlns="HSI">
      <llave>'.$key.'</llave>
      <usuario>'.$user.'</usuario>
      <password>'.$pass.'</password>
    </WSLoginUsuario>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>';

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($request_param)
);
try {
    $ch = curl_init($webservice_url);
}
catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Ecepcion: '.$ex->getMessage();
}

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_param);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

$data = curl_exec ($ch);

if ($data === FALSE) {
    printf("CURL error (#%d): %s<br>\n", curl_errno($ch),
    htmlspecialchars(curl_error($ch)));
}

curl_close ($ch);

echo 'Final: '.$data;
?>
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Checando documentación de esa librería y haciendo algunas pruebas, modifique tu código.

```
<?php
require_once("lib/nusoap.php"); 
 $client = new SoapClient('http://localost/Tintowin_WS/Tintowin_WS.asmx?WSDL');

 $error = $client->getError();
 if($error) {
     echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $error . '</pre>';
 }

 $params = array('llave'=>'XXqrD-5Z4by-6.f5J-2TQlu-TjLrK-007eA-R0l5E-2DQEc-0DhoA-L2y5y-.bJ6u-sjGiB-0W4EA-V0E5o-u3Qqr', 
        'usuario'=>'mIgueLL', 
        'password'=>'12387abwxyz');

 $regresa = $client->WSLoginUsuario($params)->WSLoginUsuario;

 print_r($regresa);
?>
```

La parte "$regresa = $client->WSLoginUsuario($params)->WSLoginUsuario;" despues del lambda tienes que darle el nombre del método al que mandas llamar pasando los parametros.